# Trouble Passing Data From Form Entry

Tags: swiftui

This is a module where the user enters transaction data and then it is saved to coreData. EntryView calls getFormData for entry of form data then calls the function saveButton() for saving the data to coreData.

Things have been working great until I recently added two additional parameters gotCountry and gotHome. These parameters are defined in EntryView. The data I want is found in getFormData but I don't want to make it available to other parts of the app until the save button is pressed (func saveButton()) hence I need to pass the data from getFormData to saveButton().

One of the two warnings is *Initialization of immutable value 'gotCountry' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it* if I place let in front of the parameters gotCountry and gotHome in getFormData. These are variables so shouldn't have let in front of them. Removing 'let' results in the error *Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'*

The parameters entryDT and entryPT are coming from form input data while gotCountry and gotHome are coming from calculated data available at time of entry.

Note that I have stripped out some of the code to see the passing of data better.

```
struct EntryView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var ctTotals: CountryTotals

    @State private var entryDT = Date()
    @State private var entryPT: Int = 0

    @State private var gotCountry: String = ""
    @State private var gotHome: Double = 0.0

    var body: some View {

        VStack (alignment: .leading){
            ShowTabTitle(g: g, title: "Enter Transaction")

            getFormData(entryDT: $entryDT, entryPT: $entryPT, gotCountry: $gotCountry, gotHome: $gotHome)

            Button {
                self.saveButton()   // button pressed
            } label: {
                Text ("Save")
            }
        }
    }

    func saveButton() {

        // save entry to core data
        let newEntry = CurrTrans(context: viewContext)

        // entry id
        newEntry.id = UUID()

        // entry date
        newEntry.entryDT = entryDT

        // entry payment type
        newEntry.entryPT = Int64(entryPT)

        ctTotals.sendTotals(gotCountry: gotCountry, gotHome: gotHome)


        do {
            try viewContext.save()

        } catch {

        }

        // reset parameters for next entry
        self.entryDT = Date()
        self.entryPT = 0
    }
}


struct getFormData: View {

    @Binding var entryDT: Date
    @Binding var entryPT: Int

    @Binding var gotCountry: String
    @Binding var gotHome: Double

    var body: some View {

        // get entry date and time
        DatePicker("", selection: $entryDT, in: ...Date())

        // select payment type
        Picker(selection: $entryPT, label: Text("")) {}

        // copy data to totals by country
        gotCountry = currencies.curItem[userData.entryCur].cunName
        gotHome = totalValue
    }
}

struct CtModel:  Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var ctName: String
    var ctHome: Double
}


 class CountryTotals: ObservableObject {

     @Published var ctItem: [CtModel] {
         didSet {
             if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(ctItem) {
                 UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: StorageKeys.ctTotals.rawValue)
             }
         }
     }
     init() {

     }


     func sendTotals(gotCountry: String, gotHome: Double) -> () {

         let item = CtModel(ctName: gotCountry, ctHome: gotHome)
         ctItem.append(item)
     }
 }
```

Comment: which line of code you got the error?

Comment: So many wrong stuffs going on here.   `ctTotals.sendTotals(gotCountry: gotCountry, gotHome: gotHome)` this is not inside your EntryView, how can you use it?(1 problem), what is this `let newEntry = CurrTrans(context: viewContext)`? it was not used and I couldn't find in your code too(2 problems), why there is a class inside a struct CtModel? (3 problems)

Comment: Read the basics again at: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html
and do the tutorial at: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/

You should not have code like this: `gotHome = totalValue` inside a view body.
Show a minimal reproducible example code that highlights your issues,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The error is occurring at the bottom of getFormData where values are stored in gotCountry and gotHome. Sorry, @EnvironmentObject var ctTotals: CountryTotals accidentally got edited out--now restored.

Comment: The actual code above is more like 400 lines. I'm trying to show the relationship between the different pieces and how information flows between them.

Comment: "The error is occurring at the bottom of getFormData where
 values are stored in gotCountry and gotHome...". As I mentioned,
 you **should not** have code like this `gotHome = totalValue`
 or `gotCountry = ...` inside a view body, it is not allowed.